# GAE with Maven & SpringMVC works in dev but not in Prod (ClassNotFound But in Dependency)

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, maven

I have a problem that I make a web application with maven ,Spring MVC and GAE.

It's works fine in local dev server,and I would like to deploy to cloud.
But It's Bad request for me that says

```
EXCEPTION java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

and I already add dependency in pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.1.0</maven>
</prerequisites>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.17</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.17</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Does it like can't get my WEB-INF/lib/*.jar?

Did I miss somthing? thx

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all your JARS in the root folder of WEB-INF/lib. There should not be any other folder inside the WEB-INF/lib folder.